# An application for a temporary management with Java

Tags: java

Hello the StackOverflow community! I am recent Java learner with 1 year of experience only. I was asked to design a software that mimics a school DB, storing all names, class, roll, and other details. When asked to, it would display appropriate messages, like calculating performance, deleting records, etc. It is yet an incomplete work but the first part (accepting and storing details) are done. I have spent a lot of time behind this and the only thing I get is a nullPointerError. Sorry, but I have been asked to stick to the basics, so no glitzy code. I have used inheritance. The superclass is "Student".

```
public class Student {
int roll,age = 0; // Roll to be auto-updated


String cl,name;
// Marks variables now
int m_eng, m_math, m_physics, m_chem, m_bio = 0;
public Student(){
}
public Student(int a, String cla){
    age = a;
    cl = cla; // Assign values

}
void setMarks(int eng, int math, int phy, int chem, int bio){
    m_eng = eng; m_math = math; m_physics = phy; m_chem = chem; m_bio = bio;
}
}
```

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Application.accept_data(Application.java:35)
at Application.execute(Application.java:23)
at Application.input(Application.java:16)
at Application.main(Application.java:101)
```

Here is the code, though:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Application extends Student {
static int n; static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static Student s[];
void input(){
    System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    s = new Student[n]; // Create array for n students
    System.out.println("Enter your choice: "); 
    System.out.println("1. Accept student's details ");
    System.out.println("2. Display all records ");
    System.out.println("3. Display data student-wise ");
    System.out.println("4. Delete record");
    System.out.println("5. Display performance status");
    System.out.println("6. Exit");
    execute();
}
static void execute(){
    boolean correct = false;
    while (!correct){
      int op = sc.nextInt();
      switch(op){
        case 1: accept_data(); correct = true;
        case 2: disp_data();correct = true;
        case 3: disp_studentwise();correct = true;
        case 4: del_record();correct = true;
        case 5: performance();correct = true;
        case 6: System.exit(0); correct = true;//Terminate
        default: System.out.println("You must enter a choice. Kindly re-enter: ");correct = false;
      }
    }
}
static void accept_data(){
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        s[i].roll = i+1; //Autoupdate roll
        System.out.println("Enter name: "); s[i].name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter age: "); s[i].age = sc.nextInt(); // Refer to object prope.
        System.out.println("Enter class: "); s[i].cl = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("We're heading for marks entry!");
        System.out.println("Enter marks in the following order: ENGLISH, MATH, PHYSICS, CHEMISTRY, BIOLOGY");
        s[i].setMarks(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("Thanks. Main menu, please enter your choice now: ");
    execute();
}
static void disp_data(){
    System.out.println("The system will display all stored information of students available.");
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        if (s[i].roll != -1){
            continue; // In case record is deleted, it won't display
        }
        else {
           printrec(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Main menu, please enter your choice: ");
    execute();
}
static void disp_studentwise(){
    System.out.println("Enter the roll number");
    int r = sc.nextInt();
    boolean ok = (r>s.length||r<0)?false:true;
    while (!ok){
        System.out.println("Incorrect roll. Please re-enter: ");
        r = sc.nextInt(); 
        if (r>s.length) ok  = false;
        else ok = true;
    }
    printrec(r-1);
    System.out.println("Main menu, please enter your choice: ");
    execute();
}
static void printrec(int n){
    int i = n;
    System.out.println("For roll number " + s[i].roll + ", details: ");
    System.out.println("Name: " + s[i].name); System.out.println("Age: " +     s[i].age);
    System.out.println("Class: " + s[i].cl); 
    System.out.println("Subject \t Marks");
    System.out.println("English: \t " + s[i].m_eng); // Display record with marks
    System.out.println("Maths: \t " + s[i].m_math);
    System.out.println("Physics: \t " + s[i].m_physics);
    System.out.println("Chemistry: \t " + s[i].m_chem);
    System.out.println("Biology: \t " + s[i].m_bio);
}
static void del_record(){
    System.out.println("Enter the roll number you want to delete: ");
    int rll = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        if (rll == s[i].roll){
            s[i].roll = -1; // Assign non-positive value to refer deleted items
        }

    }

}
static void performance(){
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Application ob = new Application();
    ob.input(); // Start program
}
}
```

Can anyone point out what's going wrong? Why there's a problem with accepting details of students after pressing for the 1st option? It shows nullPointer on s[i].roll. Keep in mind that roll is autoupdated, and user doesn't intervene there. It serves as a primary key. An explanation would be beneficial, if possible of course, I am eager to learn. Thanks.

Comment: From which line inside `accept_data()` its throwing exception ?

Comment: He said it's on `s[i].roll = i+1`

Comment: Not related to your NPE, but switch statements in Java are fall-through by default.  Your `execute()` method is going to run every command in its switch statement in a row, not just `accept_data()`.

Answer (score 0):

this :

```
s = new Student[n]; // Create array for n students
```

You are just creating an array of 'n' Student objects here ... that doesn't mean that your 'n' Students are initialized ... your array contains only 'null' values ...

you may want in your accept_data method do a :

```
for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
    s[i] = new Student();
    s[i].roll = i+1; //Autoupdate roll
```

....

Comment: But what if the user chooses a different option, such as "Display all records"? He should probably populate the array in the `input` method.

Comment: i just answered the question ;-) ... i hope, and i am sure that @Mission Coding will do the it right ...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an NPE because you create an array of `Student`s in your `input` method, but you never populate it with `Student` objects, so in `accept_data`, you're trying to access the `roll` field on a non-existent object.

You will need to fill in the array with new `Student` objects in your `input` method before you call `accept_data`.